# Update current time on column A if column C is "NO"

Tags: google-apps-script

I need a daily update setting all rows in column A to the current date/time, where they have "NO" in the C column. The rows that do not contain "NO" in column C should be left untouched.

I know how to set the trigger. I only need to code the "search in column C and set A[currentRow] to currentTime()".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and be sure to show what you have tried and researched.

Comment: What your asking for is a very easy script.  Anyone of the volunteers here could write the script.  The problem is that if you never try then you will never learn.   Everything you need to know is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app).

Answer (score 0):

### The logic to implement this functionality in a simple way would be the following:

- get the values of the cells in column C with the methods [`getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer)) and [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()).
- loop through the array containing the values with a counter variable and check for each cell with an `if` condition either its value is equal to "NO".
- If the condition is fullfilled - access the corresponding cell in column A with `getRange()` using the counter variable as the row index.
- Use the method [`setValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object)) to assign the the cell the value 
  `new Date().getTime();`.

Try to write a code following those steps. If you encounter a problem with the implementation of a specific method - feel free to post a new question about it including your code snippet and a detailed description of the problem you encounter.